# Why do we feel cold on having fever?

Tags: human-biology, pathology

Why do we feel terribly cold on catching fever of any sort, however our body becomes hotter?
Why is it that a rise in temperature makes the sufferer feel colder? Also, sweating symbolises betterment of the conditions. Why?
{This question has been asked with reference to personal experiences}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Body temperature results from a balance between the heat generated by our cells and the heat “lost” to the environment. Heat created by our cells comes from the energy used to keep us alive. Heat is lost through our skin and the air we breathe out. Human beings have an average temperature of 98.6 degrees Fahrenheit. The brain monitors body temperature and controls our bodies to keep our temperature within the normal range.

If you get a fever when you’re sick, it’s because your brain has told your body to get hotter. It directs the body to make a number of changes to correct the imbalance. Those changes include increasing heat production within the body (by shivering, for example) and reducing heat loss to the environment. Heat loss is reduced by decreasing blood flow to the skin.

Comment: Why are some fevers also accompanied by chills and shivers...like, the malarial fever...?

Comment: @Shamayeta: same reason, body try to heat up by shivering.

Comment: @Devasish Sir: My bio book refers to HAEMOZOIN that is responsible for the shiver during malaria. How does haemozoin work to raise the body heat?

Comment: @Shamayeta: Can you ask this as a separate question, it's long answer.

Comment: @Devasish Sir: I shall be doing it.